# Serve resources from a consistent URL: facebook vs Google Pagespeed

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, google-pagespeed

There is a common problem on using Facebook like button or box, on using pagespeed online sevice by Google I get this :
**Serve resources from a consistent URL**
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 25.3KiB.
- http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=7
- https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=7

it is obvious that one is for secured ssl connection and other is for unsecured connection
is there any possible way to make facebook load just one?

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do? Why not use the og:url meta tag to tell facebook one of the URLs is canonical?

Comment: i am trying to post like button and box
will this og remove this error?

Comment: I don't understand your problem - if you have two places you are accessing the same content, redirect users from one to the other - the og:url suggestion achieves the same effect for Facebook shares or likes of your links - it causes facebook to treat the two links as the same (i.e whichever URL is contained in the og:url tag is canonical, and the pages which CONTAIN the og:url are possible ways of accessing that URL's contents)

Comment: the problem is from facebook itself :)
I added the og:url
and it also loads both files
this is in all websites not just mine
and I am asking if there is a way to make facebook load just one 
see this
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fmisrstars.com_2Fvb_2Fshowthread.php_3Ft_3D412641&mobile=false&rule=ServeResourcesFromAConsistentUrl

Comment: this is not a problem of duplicate content on my site, it is duplicate content on facebook !!

Comment: Then it's out of your control

Comment: *sigh* I usually refraing from meta comments, but more constructive comments are welcome :) The problem exists - I suffer from it too - and while we cannot change Facebook code, there still might be ways to solve this issue. So I don't agree it's de facto out of our control. Bottom line: still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want Facebook to load just one, you need to serve the containing page over https.

Here's a demonstration:

Visit:

[Facebook site with HTTP](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#&mobile=false&_cachebusterhttp)

You'll notice it shows **Serve resources from a consistent URL** for xd_arbiter, now visit:

[Facebook site with HTTPS](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/&mobile=false&tab=desktop)

You'll notice Facebook only loaded the https version as we served the page over https.  I'm not sure if this is a Facebook issue.  It may be worth filing a bug with Facebook, you'll at least get some useful feedback, (I tried to but couldn't find out where you can file bugs for these things, http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ seems inappropriate)

Edit: Updating broken links, Facebook seems to have fixed the original issue and these links no longer show the problem that they used to highlight.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook supports [returning pictures over SSL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/#ssl). This may apply to other resources as well.

It might be worth appending `?return_ssl_resources=1` to your urls to see if this works for your resources. Facebook docs are notoriously incomplete, so the functionality may exist. Hope that helps!

Comment: sorry, but adding "?return_ssl_resources=1" to share url? or to all my urls??
this also btw will have a bad seo impact

Comment: Just the Facebook plugin urls.

Answer (score -1):

js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";

I suppose problem is here.

you may try to add http: to avoid connection to https:

I do not tested and can't confirm it helps or raise some issues to like button

Comment: I just thought like you :)
tried it in both ways, http and https...any way...both are loaded

Comment: That's what happens when you "do not tested". You get downvoted.